# ssl get null my session in first login

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have ssl in my e-commerce web site. At first, browser always asking "do you want to show this web site's content" in all page and when I redirect to mycart page browser shows the same alert like that "This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could comprise the safety of the entire webpage....Yes...No....". After I clicked to yes, all my sessions get null. Do you have any suggestions for me?

KR,

Çağın

Comment: is there more to this message? such as the word 'secure'? also, is this just showing for IE or all browsers?

Comment: What does 'all my sessions get null' mean?

Comment: The message says something like that, this web site contains some dangerous codes. And my sessions get null because I lost my user session, cart session.

Comment: What is the *exact* message? 'Something like' is not adequate. And losing a session does not imply 'session gets null'. That' an assumption on your part, not an actual observation. Just the observations please.

Comment: I don't take this alert in my computer but some clients get that message. That's why I don't remember full text of alert. They told that, "this web site contains some dangerous code. Do you wanto to view contents of this web site". And after they clicked yes, user and cart sessions get null. But after first login, everything will ok and the sessions don't get null.

Comment: I editted my question with the alert.

Comment: I *still* don't understand what 'sessions get null' means. Please translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your secure page is accessing information (scripts, images, etc.) from pages that are not secure. For example if you reference a javascript file (say jQuery) from a nonsecure site (say Google) then certain browsers (like IE) will display this message. You need to search through your references and find these. In other words searching `src="http` or something along those lines will pull up the nonsecure references.

Depending on what you are referencing you can move those items to your site so that they are now "secure". Also, in some cases changing your reference from `src="http` to `src="https` can resolve the problem.

Once you resolve this alert you can check again to see if you are having sessions issues as you could have some other issues to address.